# Using Eclipse UML2 to parse a Visual Paradigm generated XMI file

Tags: java, parsing, uml, xmi, visual-paradigm

I have drawn a class diagram by Visual Paradigm 8 and exported the project as XMI 2.1 file (Export for UML2). so there are two files (`test.xmi.uml` and `test.xmi.profile.uml`).
To parse `test.xmi.uml` I wrote this java code using eclipse uml2 and emf:

```
ResourceSet set = new ResourceSetImpl();
set.getPackageRegistry().put(UMLPackage.eNS_URI, UMLPackage.eINSTANCE);
set.getResourceFactoryRegistry().getExtensionToFactoryMap().put(UMLResource.FILE_EXTENSION, UMLResource.Factory.INSTANCE);
Resource.Factory.Registry.INSTANCE.getExtensionToFactoryMap().put(UMLResource.FILE_EXTENSION, UMLResource.Factory.INSTANCE);
Resource res =  set.getResource(URI.createFileURI("C:\\test.xmi.uml"), true);
EObject eobj = res.getContents().get(0);
```

but the output object (`eobj`) is an `AnyTypeImpl` which can't be read very well.
what should I do to get well formatted objects like `org.eclipse.uml2.uml.Model` objects by parsing this file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have finally found my answer:
Using `org.eclipse.uml2.uml.resources.util.UMLResourcesUtil.init()` to initialize the parameters needed to parse the `.uml` file.
So the code must be like this:

```
ResourceSet set = new ResourceSetImpl();
UMLResourcesUtil.init(set);
Resource res = set.getResource(typesUri, true);
EObject eobj = res.getContents().get(0);
```

the `eobj` is an instance of `org.eclipse.uml2.uml.Model` which is a well-formed object.